# Uma Repository pode estender uma Model?

Tags: php, laravel, ddd, solid

Se a Repository extender a Model User, estou quebrando alguns dos princípios do S.O.L.I.D?

Vi em alguns tutorias falarem, que tenho que criar uma classe abstrata com os mesmos métodos do Eloquent, isso não afere os princípios do KISS?

Como eu fiz até o momento:

```
<?php

namespace Account\Infrastructures\Domains\Models\User;

use Account\Domains\Models\User\User as UserModel;
use Account\Domains\Models\User\UserRepository;

class EloquentUserRepository extends UserModel implements UserRepository
{
    public function add(array $data)
    {
        return $this->create($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu de cara não faria um extends em Model isso acho errado pela repetição de todos os códigos que você fará nas outra classes.

Comment: @VirgilioNovic O que sugere? Já que eu quero evitar chamar nos controller s as models, por isso estou separando as responsabilidades, em services e repositories.

Comment: Eu vou propor um exemplo com repositório para ver se você entende essa parte !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crie uma `interface` base que servirá de contrato para todos as outras bases de classes Repositório do seu programa, **exemplo**:

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories\Base;

interface IRepositoryBase
{
    public function create(array $data);
    public function edit(array $data, $id);
    public function find($id);    
    public function all();
    public function delete($id);
}
```

Com essa `interface` crie a sua classe abstrata base com os comandos básicos de um `CRUD`:

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories\Base;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

abstract class RepositoryBase implements IRepositoryBase
{
    protected $model;

    public function __construct($model)
    {
        if (($model instanceof Model) === false)
            throw new \Exception("Model is invalid");
        $this->model = $model;
    }
    public function create(array $array)
    {
        return $this->model->create($array);
    }
    public function edit(array $array, $id)
    {
        $m = $this->find($id);
        if ($m)
        {
            $m->fill($array);
            if ($m->save()) return $m;
        }
        return null;
    }
    public function find($id)
    {
        return $this->model->find($id);
    }
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $m = $this->find($id);
        if ($m) return $m->delete();
        return false;
    }    
    public function all()
    {
        return $this->model->all();
    }
}
```

Esse código vai ser utilizado por todas as suas classes de entidade, ou seja, para cada entidade (`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`) vai possuir uma classe base abstrata e outra concreta para sua instânciação, ***exemplos***:

#### User

***Model User***

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = "users";    
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
    protected $hidden = ['password', 'remember_token'];
}
```

***Classe base abstrata:***

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories\Base;

use App\Models\User;

abstract class RepositoryUserBase extends RepositoryBase implements IRepositoryBase
{
    public function __construct(User $model)
    {
        parent::__construct($model);
    }
}
```

***Classe concreta:***

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Repositories\Base\RepositoryUserBase;

class RepositoryUser extends RepositoryUserBase
{
}
```

---

#### Notice

***Model Notice***

```
<?php namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notice extends Model
{
    protected $table = "notices";
    protected $primaryKey = "id";
    protected $fillable = ['title'];
}
```

***Classe base abstrata:***

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories\Base;

use App\Models\Notice;

abstract class RepositoryNoticeBase extends RepositoryBase implements IRepositoryBase
{
    public function __construct(Notice $model)
    {
        parent::__construct($model);
    }
}
```

***Classe concreta:***

```
<?php namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Repositories\Base\RepositoryNoticeBase;

class RepositoryNotice extends RepositoryNoticeBase
{
}
```

Observe que o construtor da classes Base `RepositoryNoticeBase` e `RepositoryUserBase` está sendo passado a sua classe corresponde, respectivamente, `Notice` e `User` e todo código feito na base é igual a sua grafia e padronização, mas, internamente pertence a sua configuração de `Model` que é configurado no construtor de cada classe base e pertence a sua determinada tabela, então para cada Repositório novo criado isso que é muda de um para o outro e também os nomes das classes que deve seguir a mesma lógica que as duas seguiram. Isso garante a não repetição de codificação que está na sua pergunta, claro, também esse modelo pode ser melhorado ainda mais, isso seria um padrão inicial.

Para que o `Container` e a Injeção de dependência seja configurada abra o arquivo na pasta `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` e configure da seguinte forma no método `register()`:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use App\Repositories\Base\RepositoryNoticeBase;
use App\Repositories\Base\RepositoryUserBase;
use App\Repositories\RepositoryNotice;
use App\Repositories\RepositoryUser;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{    
    public function boot()
    {    
    }
    public function register()
    {
        //
        app()->singleton(RepositoryNoticeBase::class, RepositoryNotice::class);
        app()->singleton(RepositoryUserBase::class, RepositoryUser::class);
    }
}
```

#### Para que fazer isso?

Para que funcione a injeção nos construtores ou métodos das classe de `controller` da sua aplicação, exemplo:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\Base\RepositoryNoticeBase;
use App\Repositories\Base\RepositoryUserBase;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $notice;
    private $user;
    private $request;

    public function __construct(
        RepositoryNoticeBase $notice,
        RepositoryUserBase $user,
        Request $request)
    {
        $this->notice = $notice;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function index()
    {       
        return $this->user->all();
    }
}
```

***Observação:*** se não quiser fazer essa parte é só colocar a classe Concreta direta no construtores ou métodos em vez das classes bases, **exemplo**:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\Base\RepositoryNoticeBase;
use App\Repositories\Base\RepositoryUserBase;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TestController extends Controller
{
    private $notice;
    private $user;
    private $request;

    public function __construct(
        RepositoryNotice $notice,
        RepositoryUser $user,
        Request $request)
    {
        $this->notice = $notice;
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function index()
    {       
        return $this->user->all();
    }
}
```

que terá o mesmo efeito.

<sup>***Referencia:***</sup>

- [Service Container](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/container)